# Separate query results by column value and export to multiple excel worksheets

Tags: ssms, export-to-excel

I'm using SSMS to access a very large database, with data from many locations. All of the data for all of the locations is in one table, and each location has a unique PointID. The table consists of three columns: PointID, timestamp, and data. I would like to export the data to a single excel file but separate worksheets for each location, with each worksheet titled with the PointID.

Honestly I don't know where to start with this.